# How to run single instance of toolbar for mutiple tabs/window of ie

Tags: visual-c++, com, mfc

I have developed a internet explorer toolbar in VC++,In which user needs to log-in then i just update that user details in a menu but whenever i change the tab ,the toolbar gets log-out.
How can i stop running separate instance of toolbar for each tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toolbars are in-process COM servers and IE itself uses process isolation for tabs. To make your state data survive a tab close/crash you need to move it out of IE's processes and into a broker process. You can get the state data by asking the broker process via one of interprocess communication methods (e.g. named pipe).

To sync the state between tabs, save the data to the broker process in old tab's [DWebBrowserEvents2 ::WindowStateChanged event handler](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/b48d5558-d078-4aec-a684-6498ac2231fb) and ask the broker process for the state data in the new tab's DWebBrowserEvents2 ::WindowStateChanged event handler.

Comment: thanks for the answer,But i have not understood,Can you provide me any example or anything as i am a very new to this.

Comment: check http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18866/A-Developer-s-Survival-Guide-to-IE-Protected-Mode for an example of a broker process.

Comment: Jiang:Thanks,I do have one more doubt about IE events.How can i differentiate between IE tab close and IE close.Both trigger same DISPID_ONQUIT event.

Comment: The place to cleanup is in IObjectWithSite::SetSite. There is no interface to differentiate a tab close and a window close (note IE may   still has another window and its own broker process running when you close a window)